# How to change the NextAuthorities set from custom pallet?

Tags: storage, validator, babe, pos, trait

The `NextAuthorities` is only updated in function `enact_epoch_change()` in `pallet_babe`
and this function is called in Trait `EpochChangeTrigger`  (pallet_babe) and `OnSessionHandler`

so, in the `pallet_session` how is these traits used?
and from the custom pallet, how to trigger this function/ trait to update the `NextAuthorities` set.

https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/proof-of-stake-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct and implement the [`new_session`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/9a8ef495bef273d23df6ca6c825e8ef145c1489f/substrate/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L242) for it within your custom pallet.

Then, assign this struct to the [pallet_session::Config::SessionManager](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/9a8ef495bef273d23df6ca6c825e8ef145c1489f/substrate/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L405) in your runtime configuration.

As you can see, `new_session` returns an `Option<Vec<AccountId>>`. And session pallet will use this account list to update the authorities internally.

Comment: how about BABEAuthorityWeight?